# Magento: How to synchronize the stock of multiple simple products?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, synchronize

In Magento I have created a configurable product with a couple of associated simple products. I want these simple products to synchronize stock when it changes for one of them.

For example:
I have a configurable product: T-shirt. The associated simple products are: T-shirt black, white, red and blue. Each simple product has 1 in stock.
When a black T-shirt is bought it will go out of stock, now I want the white t-shirt to synchronize and go out of stock as well.

Is there a way to link certain associated simple products together this way?

Answer (score 1):

if you only update the configurable product quantity,best solution is Go to admin>system>Import/Export>Dataflow - Profiles>Export Product Stocks

Then select only Mapped Fields in Data Format and add these required fields (screen shot below) in Field Mapping section and save and continue,

[image]

Then go to Run Profile section in your left hand side and click on Run Profile button.

Connect FTP or download your csv root/var/export/export_product_stocks.csv update product inventory or import Import/Export>Dataflow - Profiles>import Product Stocks

upload your file and same run profile.

your all product's inventory will be updated.

Thanks......

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have walked through the steps, but I doubt the end user of the webshop will want it this way. I was wondering if there is a way to make the synchronisation check automatically?